# Version of browser that works with synax code <button>

Tags: html, button

How should I know what version of different browser works based on this syntax code ?

I don't want to retrieve any bug error.

https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` tag is compatible with all browsers. You don't have any bugs with it.
Learn to use: https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/button

Answer (score 0):

It's going to work on all browsers. Even the type="reset" attribute is a part of HTML 4.01 spec.

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` works on any browser. However, there are some recent features (HTML5) about it that are not always available.

The Mozilla Developer Network is a really good reference to check this kind of information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Browser_compatibility